# What is the meaning of " law" in this case?

Tags: word-meaning

> Well, she was that frightened, she'd always been such a gatless girl,
>   that she didn't so much as know how to spin, and what was she to do
>   tomorrow with no one to come nigh her to help her? She sat down on a
>   stool in the kitchen, and **law!** how she did cry!

This content is from "Tom Tit Tot" in English fairy tales.

I know the meaning of "law" as "canon" but I think the meaning is unnatural in this context. What is the meaning of " law" in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an archaic interjection completely unrelated to the modern word "law". Compare to "lo and behold".

From http://www.dictionary.com/browse/law?s=t :

> law
>   /lɔ/ 
>   interjection, Older Use.
>   1.
>   (used as an exclamation expressing astonishment.)

Answer (score 0):

The cited ("lowbrow", "unrefined speech") usage has been declining over centuries as an "authentic" expression. It's a very thinly-disguised ***euphemism***, falling slightly short of a potentially blasphemous appeal to God - ***Lord***!

You'll usually see it transcribed as ***Lawks***! You'll sometimes encounter it even today as the (facetious, overtly "non-authentic") mock-archaic/peasant exclamation ***Lawks-a-mussy!*** = Lord have mercy [on me/us]!

---

My advice - don't use it yourself today (except facetiously, and only then *if you know when it's "appropriate"*).